# 1st Principal Component in MCA(multiple correspondence analysis) (R MASS package)

Tags: r, mass

I saw the source code of R MASS package to know its process.

(GitHub URL https://github.com/cran/MASS/blob/master/R/mca.R)

For this code, I have one question.
After SVD of matrix, the source code set the sequence as follows(line 36)

```
sec <- 1 + (1L:nf)
```

And this sequence is used to extract principal components:

```
rs <- X %*% X.svd$v[, sec]/p
```

or

```
structure(list(rs=rs, cs=cs, fs=fs, d=X.svd$d[sec], p=p, call=Call),
        class="mca")
```

Because the sequence `sec` is start `2`, above extraction means that MCA in MASS package drops the 1st principal components.

Is this process is correct?

I can't find papers or articles about this process.

If you know the reason, could you please tell me?

Comment: That's because the first singular value in this context of categorical data is always 1. You can verify this by running the first (relevant) 5 lines of code of function `mca()` in mca.R and check the value of `X.svd$d`. I cannot answer why this is so right now, but it probably has to do with the fact that the columns of the `G` matrix (computed in line 2 of the aforementioned code) are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I can check the 1st singular value and it is near to 1(about 0.98...).
And  I understand that above extraction process is to exclude trivial principal components.